# Send calendar alerts from table_calendar events to device in flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to send alerts for upcoming events from the table_calendar widget? I store the events in a Cloud Firestore db and I was just wondering if I could send them from the table_calendar widget or do I need to send them from the db.

How would I do it from the table_calendar widget or how would I do it from the db?

I don't know that I could use Cloud Functions to send an alert from the db.

Thanks.